# How to run a function in my Angular Scope from the `GoogleOnReady` function?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-ui

I'm using Angular Maps UI and have successfully loaded it back from the Google API via the script load using my API key, Google is calling my callback function correctly that was sent.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('rszmeApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'ui.map'
])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });

function onGoogleReady() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("rszmeApp"), ['rszmeApp']);
}
```

However, I want to run a function in my Angular Scope's controller from the `GoogleOnReady` function but I'm unsure how to access it from that function.

edit_***_*__*_*___**

I pass the callback like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=false&callback=onGoogleReady&libraries=geometry,drawing "></script>

 perhaps there is a way to pass the scoped function in there?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the scope of a controller from outside the angular world like so:

```
angular.element("#thingy").scope();
```

Comment: Thanks but when I do that the bootstrap process is not complete so the html that ends up with the scope has not been rendered yet. **element("#thingy").scope()** ends up undefined..

Comment: Misunderstood the question. Why do you need to call a function on scope from onGoogleReady? Can't you just call the function when the controller is created?

Comment: Nope, the **ui-maps** directive expects the Google API to be loaded, which is why we pass the global function to the google script loading tag. Thanks.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. OnGoogleReady is called when the maps api is loaded. At that point you bootstrap angular. Angular will then create the controller as part of that bootstrapping. Why wouldn't you be able to call the function from within the constructor of the controller?

Comment: That would work, how would I best do that in the controller please?

Comment: Just add the code to the body of the controller so that it runs when the controller is created: function MainCtrl($scope){ function init() { // do init stuff} init() };

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure if this is what you need but you can take a look at $broadcast and $on in AngularJS. It allows you to listen to events and broadcast them too.
Check this out [Passing Arugments to $on() in AngularJS from $emit() and $broadcast()](http://motionharvest.com/2013/03/21/passing-arugments-to-on-in-angularjs-from-emit-and-broadcast/)

Comment: Thanks, but I see that it's fine for controller to controller communication,   but I need to call the controllers function from the callback outside any angular scope.